# CakePHP Save hasOne data: constraint error

Tags: cakephp

Hey I am new to CakePHP and I want to know why my code doesnt work:

```
$data['Gender'] = array(
    'bezeichnung'   => $item['person']['GENDER']
);
$data['Client'] = array(
    'id'        => $item['person']['PERSON_ID'],
    'vorname'   => $item['person']['FIRSTNAME'],
    'nachname'  => $item['person']['LASTNAME'],
    'gender_id' => $this->Client->Gender->id
);

$this->Client->create();
$this->Client->saveAll($data);
```

I want to create a new entry in my database using the saveAll command with having $data holding all related data.

The error I get is the following:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

My Client model:

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'Gender' => array(
        'className' => 'Gender',
        'foreignKey' => 'gender_id'
    )
);
```

My Gender model:

```
public $tablePrefix = 'fixed_';
public $validate = array(
    'bezeichnung' => 'isUnique'
);
```

Comment: Don't set the `gender_id` on the data['Client'], that's automatic

Comment: I am getting the same error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: Could you update your question indicating that's the error you're getting and also your models code :) ?

Comment: There we go. I cant understand this

Comment: This `Gender` you want to save, is it always a new row in the table or only a relation? I mean, will your Gender model have one row for each Client?

Comment: No I want to automatically create a new row in the Gender table with a M for male or a W for female. There will only be 2 entries within this table for all the clients.

Comment: Then there's no need to have a saveAll. You'll have only two rows in this Gender table, so for a save, you'll only need to do (checking which is the id you want with a previous find in Gender)... $data['Client'] = array(
    'id'        => $item['person']['PERSON_ID'],
    'vorname'   => $item['person']['FIRSTNAME'],
    'nachname'  => $item['person']['LASTNAME'],
    'gender_id' => $gender_id
);  and a $this->Client->save($data)

Comment: I dont want to insert the values by hand, because i dont only have a gender table but 2 others. One of it is a group table. The data I want to import should be inserted in the group table automatically.

Comment: How do I use saveAll properly? I would like to pass the gender array and let cakephp fill the gender_id automatically.

Comment: Is this still alive? Is this because of my foreign keys, I set up in the database or am I using saveAll not properly??????